# Why CSS rule right has not effect?

Tags: html, css

My code

```html
<div style="background-color: grey; width: 900px; height: 900px;">
  <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: green; right: 50px;">
  </div>

  <div style="width: 300px; height: 200px; background-color: blue; right: 100px;">
  </div>

  <div style="width: 300px; height: 200px; background-color: yellow; right: 100px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I also read reference at here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/right . I want `right: 50px;` have affect. How to fix?

Comment: From the docs: When position is set to static, the right property has no effect. Fora a div the default position is static, so the right css property has no effect on your code

Comment: Because you are not using the absolute positioning. Did you read mentioned article thoroughly?

Comment: @emix the position absolute is not mandatory, it works even with every position except position:static

Comment: use margin-right instead of right

Comment: You can post a new answer with a new way of solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `<div>`'s doesn't got any `position` attribut.

Sample :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="position: relative; background-color: grey; width: 900px; height: 900px;">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: green; right: 50px;">

        </div>

        <div style="position: absolute; top: 200px; width: 300px; height: 200px; background-color: blue; right: 100px;">

        </div>

        <div style="position: absolute; top: 400px; width: 300px; height: 200px; background-color: yellow; right: 100px;">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set position for each `div` as follows.

```html
<div style="background-color: grey; width: 900px; height: 900px; position: relative;">
  <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: green; right: 50px; position: absolute;">
  </div>

  <div style="width: 300px; height: 200px; background-color: blue; right: 100px; position: absolute; top: 200px;">
  </div>

  <div style="width: 300px; height: 200px; background-color: yellow; right: 100px; position: absolute; top: 400px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give position attribute along with the right attribute
as `right, left, top and bottom` only works with position other than static and by default the position of all the HTML elements are static, that is why it is not working

So, You have add a position property to make this work

```
<div style="background-color: grey; width: 900px; height: 900px; position: relative">
  <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: green; right: 50px; position: absolute">
  </div>

  <div style="width: 300px; height: 200px; background-color: blue; right: 100px; position: absolute">
  </div>

  <div style="width: 300px; height: 200px; background-color: yellow; right: 100px; position: absolute">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There was a small mistake, I have edited my answer. It should work now

Comment: You have to add position:absolute to remove the element from the normal flow and give the parent position relative so that it will set with respect to the parent